# Win XP vs Win7, when sending credentials to the remote server, is there a difference?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, windows-xp, com

On a 2003 windows server I have a com+ application which is available to its clients
on everybody, anonymous permissions.
Windows XP machnes doesn't have problems with accessing, activating, lanuching com+ object, however windows 7 client has some troubles.

When Win7 user tries to connect to to com+, it gets an error that the remote object doesn't implement IDispatch interface. I reckon it is security issue.

When i set the same user on the client and remote machine problem is solved but it is not a solution, Win 7 should get access to com+ being in everybody/anonymous group.

Is there a difference in sending credentials in xp/win7? What can I set on win7 machine to solve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried running the application as an administrator? (right click -> "Run as Administrator")

Answer (score 1):

It might be either a local administrator / UAC issue or possibly an authentication protocol problem. By default Windows 7 doesn't support NTLM v1 or LM authentication. Several of the COM+ services I've seen didn't support NTLM v2 or Kerberos, only the older methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Probably the answer was that on the client machine, additional library wasn't installed which included interface used in communication.

Without it com+ client probably wanted to fetch interface definition from a remote server, with no luck.